# Function done() not recognized by jest with typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, testing, jestjs

I am trying to use the done() function inside a test as follow :

```js
it('button click -> call selectProduct', async () => {
  // wrapper is defined properly in a beforeEach() with shallowMount()
  const spy = jest.spyOn(wrapper.vm, 'selectProduct');
  wrapper.find('button').trigger('click');
  setTimeout(() => {
      expect(spy).toBeCalledTimes(1);
      done();
  });
});
```

But vscode tells me `Cannot find name 'done'`. `done` is however used without import statement in the documentation. What I have done wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you've missed to accept it as argument in your test callback

```
it('button click -> call selectProduct', async ( done ) => {
                                                ^ here
```